# What is wrong with [a b] = randi()

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble with this command

```
[a b]=randi(5,1,2)
```

matlab tells me
Too many output arguments.
Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: In case you wonder why it should only be one output when you want two numbers: you get all numbers in a vector/array, not as separate variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is obvious here as there should be only one output for `randi()`.

```
r = randi(imax,n)
r = randi(imax,m,n)
r = randi(imax,[m,n])
r = randi(imax,p1,...,pn)
r = randi(imax,[p1,...,pn])
r = randi(imax)
r = randi(imax,size(A))
r = randi([imin,imax],...)
r = randi(..., classname)
```

Check out its [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for more info.

Comment: just to add specificity to the original question, you probably want `r = randi(5,1,2); a = r(1); b = r(2);` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As @hero mentioned, you should just get a vector as output of `randi`.

If you really must get it to different letters, here is how it could be done:

```
c = num2cell(randi(5,1,2));
[a, b] = deal(c{:});
```

Needless to say, this is not something you should usually want.